# QueryDSL - subquery alias

Tags: java, postgresql, querydsl

So, I want to get list of entities with count of specific data from my db. I use QueryDSL 4.1.3 and postgres. I have subquery, which counts specific data for each entity. I got something like this and it works:

```
JPAQuery<?> countQuery = from(sideEntity)
  .join(..).on(..)
  ..
  .select(sideEntity.countDistinct);

JPAQuery<?> mainQuery = from(mainEntity)
  .innerJoin(..).on(..)
  ..
  .where(..);

return mainQuery(mainEntity, countQuery).fetch();
```

What I need is to order by countQuery result. Following sql works on my db

```
select distinct
  t0.id as a1
  ..
  (select count(distinct (t2.id) from .. where .. ) as countAlias
from .. where ..
group by ..
order by countAlias desc
```

So I want to know if it's possible in queryDSL to set an alias to subquery result and then order by this alias.